# Beautiful Soup KeyError 'href' but the definitely exist

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, href

Trying to pull all the links from a site. I get the "KeyError: 'href' " but as I understand it, this only applies when there are  tags without href present. However, when I look through the soup object, EVERY a tag has an href. So I don't get why I'm seeing this error. I've looked this up a lot and everyone always just mentions a tags without href.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
import requests

page_count = 1
catalog_page = f"https://40kaudio.com/page/{str(page_count)}/?s"

while page_count < 4:
    print(f"Begin Book Scrape from {catalog_page}")
    # Soup opens the page.
    open_page = requests.get(catalog_page)
    # We create a soup object that has all the page stuff in it
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open_page.content, "html.parser")
    # We iterate through that soup object and pull out anything with a class of "title-post"
    for link in soup.find_all('h2', "title-post"):
        print(link['href'])

else:
    print('By the Emperor!')
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `href` tag in `link`. However, there is an `a` tag in `link` and an `href` attribute in the `a` tag.

```html
<a href="https://40kaudio.com/justin-d-hill-cadia-stands-audiobook/" rel="bookmark">Justin D. Hill &#8211; Cadia Stands Audiobook</a>
```

```py
for link in soup.find_all('h2', "title-post"):
    print(link.a['href'])
```

Don't forget to increment `page_count` in your `while` loop.